# Anaconda Spyder cant open

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to open Spyder on root and I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.core.inputtransformer2'
```

This error has been shown after trying to install a package with `pip` (and Spyder crashed).

I have even uninstalled Anaconda completely and reinstalled but the problem persists.

I had created a virtual environment where at least I can launch Spyder from here. But on root I just cant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What was the package you installed?

Comment: I'm not sure since I was trying to replicate an article I was reading but I think PyDrive caused this mess. Here is the article I followed https://searchengineland.com/build-seo-seasonality-projections-with-google-trends-in-python-329384

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 (and have added path variable on installation)

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as the command(s) used.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem a while ago. You can upgrade IPython using the following command. Hope it resolves your issue.

```
conda update IPython -n envname
```

envname is the name of the environment you are trying to work in. Also, you might want to install sudo in the correct environment too if you haven't done already.

```
conda install -c odsp-test sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

check all the requirements from the spyder installation page,

> https://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html

update or install the requirements that are missing. This should work for you.

Comment: olny way to make it work is checking all the required dependencies. I have faced this type of problems many time. welcome